# Error: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, ecmascript-6, mime-types

I am sending a PDF stream from my server to the client and then displaying that PDF in an `<object>` tag in the client. Here is my code:

**server.js**

```
router.get('/pdf', function * () {
  var stream = getMyFileStream();
  this.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  this.response.body = stream;
});
```

**client.js**

```
var objectElement = document.querySelector('object');

fetch('/pdf', request)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(url => {
    objectElement.setAttribute('data', url)
    objectElement.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf')
  })
```

This code seems to work correctly, however I get the following warning in my console:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

Why does it think my resource should be `text/html`? If I change my `Content-Type` header to `text/html`, it makes the warning go away but it obviously causes a rendering issue of the PDF. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the `type` of `blob`? Message at `console` is warning, not  `Error`, yes?

Comment: Hi - could you check my answer please and confirm if it works. I am after the +50 bounty if at all possible.

Comment: Heh meh_programmer, select an answer please.

Answer (score 3):

In your fetch statement you need to set a header type because the default will be document. Since you have not specified the matching content the browser is letting you know something hooky is happening.

```
// to stop browser complaining use a request object to specify header
var request = new Request('/pdf', {
    headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
    })
});

fetch(request)
.then(function() { /* handle response */ });
...
```

Note: This is from my own evaluation research of the fetch api. I have not yet used it in anger so this is untested. I found this site useful https://davidwalsh.name/fetch.

Let me know how you get on please.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because there's a redirect from /pdf and/or there is no file extension.

Add this extra header:

```
this.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=results.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It didn't seem to fix the issue however. One thing I noticed though is that when I changed it from an `<object>` tag to an `<embed>` tag, the warning went away. Does the `src` attribute in `<embed>` work differently than the `data` attribute in `<object>`?

Comment: Not sure but what if you add a type attribute like this? <object data="/pdf" type="application/pdf">

Comment: I updated my client code with what I currently have. When I added the `objectElement.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf')` line, chrome dev tools now says that is where the warning message is coming from. If I remove that line, dev tools doesn't tell you where the message is coming from. Very weird :|

Comment: Can you post the server response headers which you can get on the Network tab in chrome dev tools?

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/NAIDaRb.png) are the three requests that are getting sent. The `generate` is a POST request that triggers the creation of the PDF stream, the `display` is the GET request that retrieves the stream and then displays it, and I think that third one is coming from using `Blob`. Here are the headers for [1](http://i.imgur.com/GcAIWLW.png) [2](http://i.imgur.com/GK5G6S7.png) and [3](http://i.imgur.com/9YhxVQK.png).